# When does the ReadCallBack get called in this example?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am having a bit of nightmare understanding the asynchronous socket communication model in .net.  Can someone please tell me when does the ReadCallBack method get called( I am using an asyn server to listen on a port) ( the MS link is below for full code if needed)

```
//handler is my server socket handler
handler.BeginReceive( state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize,
 0,new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
```

i.e. when it has *finished*receiving data or when it has *detected*that some data is coming in. In other words, when the ReadCallBack does get called, how does it know that the data is not arriving any more? If the data keeps arriving ,will the ReadCallBack keep getting called? I mean it is not like my client is sending something like a "\n" delimiter, so how do I check in the readcallback method what is being sent in a line? My client is actually sending a ping every 10 seconds( the iAmAlive ping) , apart from a single "hello_My name is" message upon first connection.

thanks

This is the example i am trying to understand [Microsoft Async Server socket example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback knows that no data is arriving any longer if you tell it to. You can do that with the state object. If you check the example you linked that in the `ReadCallback()` method the sb property of the state object gets examined (i.e. the string that was received). If it contains `"<EOF>"` it falls through and ends the callback by calling `EndInvoke` behind the scenes. As long as sb does not contain `"<EOF>"` the callback continues to try to read.

Answer (score 2):

The method you are invoking is defined as:

```
[HostProtectionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, ExternalThreading = true)]
public IAsyncResult BeginReceive(
    byte[] buffer,
    int offset,
    int size,
    SocketFlags socketFlags,
    AsyncCallback callback,
    Object state
)
```

The AsyncCallback(ReadCallback) parameter you are passing is a delegate *pointer* to a method, that the sender should call upon completion of the receive operation.

```
callback
Type: System.AsyncCallback
An AsyncCallback delegate that references the method to invoke when the operation is complete.
```

I think of socket communications as a series of messages in a single channel.

Readcallback "knows" its at the end of a particular message data because that callback method is being called. i.e. it's called post transfer of all data for a given message.

If you interrogate the received data and it also contains the end of all messages marker according to the protocol you have devised i.e. EOF whatever, then you should also close  the connection.

You can also put additional context in the state object (and use casting to type it) that you can check // refer to in your call back method.

So what the client "knows" comes down to what you devise. That's one of the beauties of using a raw socket. You devise the protocol and you can make it as simple or sophisticated as you like. If someone else determined the protocol then you get the docs for that or otherwise ask them.

In your example part of the protocol is that "EOF" means end of file / transfer. It could just as easily be "Bananas" if you wanted it to be and then you'd look for "Bananas" in a message and if you found it you'd close the channel.

Answer (score 1):

As stated on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3sah14d0.aspx) this particular callback is invoked, as soon as the asynchronous method has ended.
If you are unsure, you should read the documentation (if available, of course, but MSDN offers much information).

Comment: Trust me I have done so much reading up but still I can't wrap my head around the whole model. What exactly does "end" mean, ?

Comment: When the thread, which executes the particular method, has reached the end of the method-body.